# getting exception error -SPFieldType.File -"Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."

Tags: custom-field-types

creating a **Field** of type **File and Attachments** in document library and getting exception error as mentioned above.Please help me out thanks in advance..

```
Guid listid1 = web.Lists.Add("TESTLIBRARY", "THIS LIST IS FOR TESTING", 
                             SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary);

SPList documentlibrary = web.Lists["TESTLIBRARY"];
documentlibrary.ContentTypesEnabled = true;

documentlibrary.Fields.Add("Employee Attachments", SPFieldType.File, false);
                    documentlibrary.Update();
```

Answer (score 1):

Having attachments on document libraries and surveys is not supported.

In addition, you don't *add an attachments column* to a list in general. The way to enable attachments is to set the EnableAttachments property on a list to true.

```
SPList list = web.Lists["LISTNAME"]; 
list.EnableAttachments = true;
list.Update();
```

The code above will throw an exception if the list is a document library or survey